# SQL Query Builder and Charting

Tags: sql, graph, charts, builder

I'm looking for a product that can be placed into an ASP.NET page which will allow users to build their own queries to produced a data set, of which they can create their own reports/charts/graphs based on the data set.

I've looked into EasyQuery.NET, which has a query builder similar to what I'm looking for, but it does not have charting abilities.  I've also seen SiSense's product, which allows users to build their own queries and create reports/charts/graphs based on the results, but it is too expensive for me.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Rusty

Comment: Have you seen this similar post? It is not specifically related to an ASP.NET control, but it may be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746177/is-there-a-report-tool-that-allows-users-to-create-their-own-reports

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) and in particular, [Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx) to allow your users to not only view reports, but also create their own, subscribe to them, etc.
Charting is one of the capabilities of the Report Builder see this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239351.aspx), for example.